# How can I change the cell content in a ListView through code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I'm dynamically creating a WPF window with a grid-like presentation. There is a header row that contains the column headers. It must always be visible. Below that there is a large number of rows (like hundreds) that can be vertically scrolled. Each row contains a text in the first column and a checkbox in each remaining column.

The list of columns and rows is dynamic, so creating a viewmodel class and binding with templates doesn't work (or would at least be very complicated and require much code while giving up the dynamic nature of the problem). Also, with each checkbox interaction in one row, all other rows might be affected (for the same column) and need to be updated. This would need a lot of interaction between all individual row viewmodels.

I'm looking for a solution to create the columns and rows of an existing empty `ListView` control and populate all of its data, checkboxes and interaction entirely in C# code.

Specifically I'm missing some `ListView` method that lets me set the content of a specific cell. While I can add columns to the ListView's `GridView.Columns` collection, I can't go anywhere from there without templates and bindings. Is is possible to use WPF like this?

Comment: Setting a "cell" in a ListView basically means to set the corresponding property of the row data item, i.e. the corresponding element from the ItemsSource collection of the ListView. A GridView expects that all row items expose the same set of properties. You may however use a DataTemplateSelector as a GridViewColumn's CellTemplateSelector to choose between different DataTemplates for different cell values.

Comment: The problem is that when I use a template for, say, a checkbox column, all checkboxes do exactly the same an no customisation is possible anymore because I don't create each checkbox, instead WPF creates them for me.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I use a template for, say, a checkbox column, all checkboxes do exactly the same an no customisation is possible anymore because I don't create each checkbox, instead WPF creates them for me.

You may create a specific `CellTemplate` for each `GridViewColumn` using either `XamlReader.Parse`:

```
const string Xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x = \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">" +
    "<CheckBox Content=\"{Binding Name}\" IsChecked=\"{Binding IsChecked}\" />" +
    "</DataTemplate>";
column.CellTemplate = XamlReader.Parse(Xaml) as DataTemplate;
```

...or a `FrameworkElementFactory`:

```
FrameworkElementFactory checkBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
checkBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.ContentProperty, new Binding("Name"));
checkBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("IsChecked"));
column.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = checkBox };
```

This lets you customize the columns but still use the `GridView` and its functionlity the way you are supposed to. Trying to modifying the generated visual elements is not recommended, especially not if you are using the UI virtualization.